# JCAPS Build Error

Tags: jcaps

I am new to JCAPS and trying to build a sample project where I will read a file and write the content to the file system.

I have created the JCD, connectivity map and deployment profile using edesigner 5.1.3.

However when I am building the project, I am getting the error:

> There are uncommitted source code changes, please commit the changes
>   before activation

Even though I don't have any code checked-out.

Could you please let me know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCAPS is notoriously cryptic. In this instance, it is trying to tell you that you've changed your JCD, but not hit the green commit button in the JCD editor (bottom left). To fix this, open the JCD, hit the commit button, hit the validate button (top middle) then save it. For good measure, I would also commit the JCD file itself.

[image: jcd uncommitted change]

As an aside, if you can avoid using JCAPS altogether, I'd suggest Mirth for light weight integration projects and camel for everything else.

Comment: If it helped, maybe you can accept the answer or at least upvote it?